# Is it possible to do a multivariate unsupervised anomaly (outlier) detection in ML.Net?

Tags: machine-learning, outliers, ml.net, anomaly-detection

I am trying to find a solution to perform a multivariate unsupervised anomaly (outlier) detection in ML.Net.
Does anyone already have a working solution?

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of any algorithm in ML.NET that can perform anomaly detection (or one-class classification, as asked in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58606955/is-it-possible-to-do-one-class-classification-with-microsoft-ml-net)).

My suspicion is that it is not possible at the moment.